# Excel Web Services/Pivot Filters not functioning and MOSS 2007 

Tags: 2007, excel-services

I am currently struggling with an issue with Excel Web Servces and pivot tables.   We have several site collections in which we expose pivot tables with filters through EWA web parts.  The issue is that the filters that are usedin pivot tables don't execute and return nothing.  You click on the filter and it just spins.   Here is where it gets odd.  There is a site collection on the same farm where the same reports work fine.  I have compared many settings and at this point comparing apples to apples between the collection.

Unfortunately I don't have back end access so it would be tough to take a look at Central Administration.

What other options do I have at this point?   This has been escalated to our infrastructure team and they have since involved Microsoft.   I am just concerned that I am missing something obvious.

One thing I will add is that upon creating a new report center site the sample dashboard that is created also exhibits the same behavior.  The pivot filters wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue to the Excel pivot table issue we had on our farm.   I have to say it took Microsoft a bit of time to realize that it was a setting in the web.config.

As we discussed it appears you have found the cause of the issue with the filter and sort buttons not working in certain web apps.  In comparing the web.config of the broken web application vs. a functional one you noticed the following line was different in the nonworking web app.

Working:

```
<pages enableSessionState="false"
    enableViewState="true"
    enableViewStateMac="true"
    validateRequest="false"
    pageParserFilterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    asyncTimeout="7">
```

Broken:

```
<pages enableSessionState="true"
       enableViewState="true"
       enableViewStateMac="true"
       validateRequest="false"
       pageParserFilterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
       asyncTimeout="30"
       enableEventValidation="false">
```

I didn't have access to the Servers to find this out for myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think that seeing the back end might help, but there are some things that I would ask. Is the data you are trying to view on the same site collection or are you crossing site collections. Do you have permissions to the data on that site collection. Just a few things to make sure of. Can you find out if there are any errors on the servers? The infrastructure team should be able to look at the servers to see if they have errors. It is an odd problem!

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  It is a strange issue.  They key here is the back end access.  The infrastructure team is working with Microsoft on this and all the logs have been sent.  So I guess I am in good hands there.  I hope :)   It just seems like something obvious I might of been missing from my angle.  However, I am at the point that where I am confident that this is a infrastructure issue and have exhausted client side options.
 Thanks for the reply.